# Invalid <node> tag: node name cannot contain a namespace

Tags: ros, astra

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sibot@sibot1:~/new_ver_ws$ roslaunch -v segway_bringup segway_astra.launch 
... logging to /home/sibot/.ros/log/93c6fb7a-28d2-11e7-bb49-0001c01bc206/roslaunch-sibot1-14348.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

... loading XML file [/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros/roscore.xml]
... executing command param [rosversion roslaunch]
Added parameter [/rosversion]
... executing command param [rosversion -d]
Added parameter [/rosdistro]
Added core node of type [rosout/rosout] in namespace [/]
... loading XML file [/home/sibot/new_ver_ws/src/segway_v3_robot/segway_bringup/launch/sensors/segway_astra.launch]
... loading XML file [/home/sibot/new_ver_ws/src/segway_v3_robot/third_party_sensors/ros_astra_launch/launch/astra.launch]
... loading XML file [/opt/ros/indigo/share/rgbd_launch/launch/includes/manager.launch.xml]
Added parameter [/segway/front_astra/segway/front_astra_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads]
while processing /home/sibot/new_ver_ws/src/segway_v3_robot/third_party_sensors/ros_astra_launch/launch/astra.launch:
while processing /opt/ros/indigo/share/rgbd_launch/launch/includes/manager.launch.xml:
Invalid <node> tag: node name cannot contain a namespace. 

Node xml is <node args="manager" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)" name="$(arg name)" output="screen" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet">
     <param name="num_worker_threads" value="$(arg num_worker_threads)"/>
  </node>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260096/invalid-%3Cnode%3E-tag:-node-name-cannot-contain-a-namespace./) by [Aswin Sarang](https://answers.ros.org/users/27924/aswin-sarang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-24

Post score: -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

omg, please have the dececny to formulate a question...

I mean, there is a clear error output you found, google for it. If you then don't find an answer, ask a question, and provide some helpful input. It is clear that the problem lies with the `name="$(arg name)"  case, is it not?

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3